# Trying to print the line a string appears in a text file

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am analysing an episode of Brooklyn 99 specifically trying to find the line number in a text file where Gina says Scully looks 'like an eggplant' but my code isn't working, any help would be appreciated, I am using jupyter and not getting an error message when running my code.

```
f = open(r'C:\Users\bubba\Downloads\B99_episode_.txt', 'r')
print(f)

# Choosing TERRY 

# Initialising the value of count as -1 because it appears in the cast list 

count = -1

terry_in_f = f.readlines()
for line in terry_in_f:
    if 'TERRY' in line:
        count = count + 1 
print(count)

# Finding the line number in which Gina states 'like an eggplant'
for index, line in enumerate(f):
    if line.lower() == "like an eggplant":
        print(index)
        break
```

Comment: I assume you are opening the file as f?

Comment: Yes, just edited that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

`if "like an eggplant"` will always enter the block because "like an eggplant" isn't falsey. You need to check the actual line from the file is equal to the string you're looking for. So it should be `if line == "like an eggplant"`.

Also, you want to print the line number. You can use `enumerate()` to give you the index of the line you're on instead of just printing the actual line itself.

```
for index, line in enumerate(f):
    if line.lower() == "like an eggplant":
        print(index)
        break
```

Lastly, instead of doing a hard comparison of `if line == "like an eggplant":`, it may be better to do `if "like an eggplant" in line:`. This will return true if the string "like an eggplant" is in the script line, even if there is some surrounding noise. For example, if the script says "Gina: like an eggplant", having a direct comparison would return false. Checking if the string is inside the line would return True. It gives you more flexibility.

Comment: not quite worked, I haven't indexed anything yet, plus I want the specific line it refers to, not just whether the statement is empty or not,

thank you for your help

Comment: "I haven't indexed anything yet" What do you mean? `enumerate(f)` will index the line numbers for you.

Comment: "not whether the statement is empty or not" Again, what do you mean? My code isn't checking if it's empty, its checking if your line is equal to "like an eggplant".

Comment: When I run the program through IDLE, it highlights the comma and states invalid syntax

Comment: I just ran my code in the intepreter and it worked. Are you sure you copied it exactly? `index, line in enumerate(f)`, not just `index, line in f`

Comment: I copied it exactly and it hasn't given me an error message but it didnt give me a line number

Comment: Silly question but did you type it or copy/paste? copy/pasting has weird formatting issues. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I didn't copy/paste, I've just edited my code to show ALL of my work including the previous question, bearing in mind its all in the same kernal

Comment: Do `f.seek(0)` right before the code I told you. You read all the lines once, so there's nothing else to read. Seeking to 0 will put you at the start of the file. That should fix your error. Then you can figure out how to combine your two loops into one, so you dont need to loop the file twice.

Comment: @Hiddenspaceship Hopefully that fixed it for you. If so please approve. Otherwise let me know in another comment. But it really should have.